# What are the limitations when it comes to calling things from objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, variables, object

I am having trouble with a line of code

```
    if(words[i].endsWith(oneD[x].ending))
```

works,

```
    var thing = "oneD";
    if(words[i].endsWith([thing][x].ending))
```

doesn't. I want them to both do the same thing.

Comment: `[thing][x]` — you're creating array of a single element `thing` and then trying to access `x` element of it. Which will work only if `x === 0`, then it returns `thing` and `undefined` otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A property of an object can be accessed in two equivalent ways:

```
obj.prop
obj['prop']
```

Your example doesn't work because you don't have a property of an object there, but a variable.

A solution to your problem could come from the fact that variables declared in the global scope also appear as properties of the global object (`window` in case of browsers):

```
var ans = 42;
console.log(window.ans); // 42
```

So if oneD is a variable in the global scope, the following two lines are equivalent:

```
if(words[i].endsWith(oneD[x].ending))
if(words[i].endsWith(window['oneD'][x].ending))
```

Obviously instead of the literal string 'oneD' you could place a variable which evaluates to that string (`thing` in your example).

Comment: Upvoted, but I have a slight problem with your answer. What if the element is not part of the global scope? I believe my answer covers that case as well.

Comment: @LajosArpad I'm afraid your answer is incorrect. `this[thing]` only works in the global scope in non-strict mode because `this` in the global scope resolves to the global object. `function f(){ var x = 42; console.log(this['x']); } f();` will log `undefined`.